# How does a GM know they have done enough prep?

Tags: gm-techniques

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When GMing a game, how much should you prepare in advance?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/5870/when-gming-a-game-how-much-should-you-prepare-in-advance)

How do you, as a GM, keep from getting into an endless prep loop and to know when you have enough to run a scenario, a session, an encounter or a campaign? What tools do you use to properly ensure preparation?

In short, how do you project manage your games?