# How much should I prepare as a new DM for a play session?

Tags: dnd-5e, gm-techniques, gm-preparation

I'll be a DM for a group of my friends soonish for a play through of the D&D 5 starter set campaign. I've played with this group for a few months but some more experienced players have been taking over the role of DM. Since it is now my turn and I haven't done this before, my question is how much time should I invest in creating a story beforehand? How much detail should I put into storylines when preparing? I want the players to feel like they are in control of where the story goes, which likely means I will encounter situations I am unprepared for no matter what. How do some more experienced DMs deal with this? Are there any tips for a newbie to start this off on the right foot with my players? All advice is appreciated!

Comment: possible duplicate of [When GMing a game, how much should you prepare in advance?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/5870/when-gming-a-game-how-much-should-you-prepare-in-advance)

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site! We’re a little different from discussion forums you may be used to; I recommend checking out the [Tour]. Because this question is much too broad for us to effectively answer – the answer to this question depends a *lot* on your preferences, your players’ preferences, the kind of campaign you’re trying to run, the medium you’re running it on, so on and so forth. We like questions that are focused and can be concisely and definitively answered – for the system to work, we need to be able to say “*this* answer is better than *that* answer.”

Comment: (or there could just be a question exactly like yours that was allowed when the site was newer; hopefully it will help, and if you have more specific questions after reading those answers, you might be able to ask the kind of focused question we love to answer.) Anyway, it’s a *good* question, just not for *here*, so enjoy a +1. Get a few more, and you can join the [Chat], where we’d be happy to share our personal preferences.

Comment: Alright, I'll keep that in mind and see if I can edit the question. Thank you! I'll check the tour.